# Set symbol description to an attribute field

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, fields-attributes, legend, unique-value

ArcGIS Pro. I would like to show the patch, label, and description in the legend of my map. I found the description feature in symbology, but it seems like it has to be filled in manually. I would like to set it to an existing attribute field. Is there a way to do this? It seems crazy that I would have to enter each individually.

[image]